# Error while trying to download CopernicusDEM for a country in R

Tags: r, gis

I am new to using mapping tools in R. I would like to download the 30 m Copernicus DEM for Egypt. After creating an sf file for Egypt, creating the bounding box and setting the CRS to the Copernicus CRS (4326), I use the "aio_geom_sav_tif_matches" function. I get the following error message:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "'"aws"' not found"
> In addition: Warning message:
> In st_is_longlat(x) :
> bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data"

The code is:

```
country <- getData("GADM", 
                   country = "EGY", 
                   level=0)

#convert to sf format
Egypt<-as(country, "sf")

#set directory
dem_dir = tempdir()

#Find CRS of Egypt
crs(Egypt)

#Transform to new CRS (4199 = Egypt 1930)
st_transform(Egypt,4326)

X<-st_as_sfc(st_bbox(Egypt), crs=4326)


#Download DEM30 from Copernicus using Egypt
dem30 = CopernicusDEM::aoi_geom_save_tif_matches(sf_or_file = X,
                                                 dir_save_tifs = dem_dir,
                                                 resolution = 30,
                                                 crs_value = 4326,
                                                 threads = parallel::detectCores(),
                                                 verbose = TRUE)
```

I assume there is something quite basic that i am not getting with the function. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have 'awscli' configured in your Operating System. You can view more info in the Github repository of the package, in the section System Requirements (https://github.com/mlampros/CopernicusDEM#copernicusdem).

Moreover, your example does not include the R packages required (is not reproducible). The following works for me for your use case ('Egypt'), slightly modified,

```
require(raster)
require(sf)

country <- raster::getData("GADM", 
                           country = "EGY", 
                           level=0)

#convert to sf format
Egypt <- as(country, "sf")

#set directory
dem_dir = tempdir()
dem_dir

#Transform to new CRS (4199 = Egypt 1930)
Egypt = sf::st_transform(Egypt, crs = 4326)

X <- sf::st_as_sfc(sf::st_bbox(Egypt), crs = 4326)


#Download DEM30 from Copernicus using Egypt
dem30 = CopernicusDEM::aoi_geom_save_tif_matches(sf_or_file = X,
                                                 dir_save_tifs = dem_dir,
                                                 resolution = 30,
                                                 crs_value = 4326,
                                                 threads = parallel::detectCores(),
                                                 verbose = TRUE)

# Parallel download of the  141  .tif files using  8  threads starts ...
```

Comment: Thanks Lampros. I was unaware of the need to install awscli. This now works, Much appreciated